# Char input in C programming

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
int p3_2_4()
{
    char cargo[100];

    printf("Valor: ");
    scanf("%s", cargo);

    if (cargo == "C")
        printf("Chefe");
    else if (cargo == "o")
        printf("operario");
    else if (cargo == "i")
        printf("inspetor");
    else if (cargo == "m")
        printf("mecanico");
    else
        printf("O valor inserido nao tem correspondencia.");

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to use char type, I searched for many types of char input, but unfortunately I couldn't find my answer. I hope you can clarify me.

Comment: What problems are you having ?

Comment: can you please explain what sort of input you want? something else than scanf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"C" isn't a char type. Proof:

```
printf("sizeof \"C\" == %zu\n", sizeof "C");
printf("sizeof (char) == %zu\n", sizeof (char));
```

Rather, it is a `const char[2]` type; "C" is a string literal. String literals translate to strings, and strings are terminated by an extra `'\0'` character. This explains the extra character.

I think you want `getchar()` and `'C'` (which are unsigned char values stored as `int`) rather than `scanf("%s", ...)` and `"C"`, if you only intend to be using one character from the input.

```
int cargo = getchar();
if (cargo == 'C')
    puts("Chefe");
else if (cargo == 'o')
    puts("operario");
else if (cargo == 'i')
    puts("inspetor");
else if (cargo == 'm')
    puts("mecanico");
else
    puts("O valor inserido nao tem correspondencia.");
```

This problem seems like it'd be easy for anyone reading one of our fine books. Which book are you reading? It seems for me as though you might be ready for K&R's "The C Programming Language".

Answer (score 2):

`char[100]` isn't a `char` it is an *array* of characters (a string). If you want to compare strings in C you can use the `strcmp(a, b)` or `strncmp(a, b, n)` functions from the `string.h` header file.

```
char name[] = "Hunter";

if(!strcmp(name, "Hunter")) // if the return value of strcmp is 0 
{
   puts("It's me!");
}
else
{
   puts("Not me.");
}
```